# Split by regex containing one entire string or another in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm attempting to parse a log file, where each line starts with one of: `[DEBUG]`, `[INFO]`, `[WARNING]`, or `[ERROR]`.

I would like to parse this into a list where each element contains one log message, including the log level that I am splitting by. For example, a log file containing the following:

```
[INFO]: Waiting for application shutdown.
[INFO]: Application shutdown complete.
[INFO]: Finished server process
```

should result with individual elements like the following:
`[INFO]: Waiting for application shutdown.`

I am attempting to use Python's regex split method to make this happen, but I cannot get the the log level to be included with the remainder of the log message.

My current code (`all_logs` is the string containing the entirety of the log file):

```
logLevelRegex = "(\[(DEBUG)|(INFO)|(WARNING)|(ERROR)\])"
split_logs = re.split(logLevelRegex, all_logs)
print(split_logs)
```

The resulting list contains elements that are individual brackets, None values, log levels, and the remainder of log messages.

Apologies if this has been asked before; I assume it has in some form or another, but I cannot find anything that handles this situation.

Comment: Is it not enough to just split on newlines?

Comment: Try `logLevelRegex = r"(\[(?:DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR)\])"`

Comment: if you split this way you lose the log level

Comment: It wasn't enough to split by newlines because some log entries span multiple lines, such as error tracebacks

Comment: Then your examples should show examples of your use cases.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using re.split you can use re.findall and match all lines with the pattern starting at the beginning of the string prepending `^` and match the rest of the line with `.*` after it.

If there can be optional lines after it, you can match those by optionally repeating a newline and the lines that does not start with any of the log levelsl

```
^\[(?:DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR)].*(?:\n(?!\[(?:DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR)]).*)*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b6EfII/1) for the matches.

Example:

```
import re
all_logs = ("[INFO]: Waiting for application shutdown.\n"
            "[INFO]: Application shutdown complete.\n"
            "[INFO]: Finished server process")

logLevelRegex = r"^\[(?:DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR)].*(?:\n(?!\[(?:DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR)]).*)*"
split_logs = re.findall(logLevelRegex, all_logs, re.M)
print(split_logs)
```

Output

```
[
  '[INFO]: Waiting for application shutdown.',
  '[INFO]: Application shutdown complete.',
  '[INFO]: Finished server process'
]
```

---

If you want to use re.split, you can use a positive lookahead `(?=` and filter out the empty entries:

```
split_logs = [s for s in re.split(r"(?=^\[(?:DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR)])", all_logs) if s]
```

Comment: This works wonderfully for most of the log entries but doesn't catch the entirety of multiline log entries. When there is an error traceback it only catches the first line with the [ERROR] log level

Comment: @MichaelPesce I see, I have updated the answer, now getting all the following lines that do not start with the Log level.

Comment: I like this one (+1). However, be `DRY` and avoid nested quantifiers. That being said, you could use a subroutine (with the `regex` module) with https://regex101.com/r/Vij8mH/1

Comment: @Jan That is indeed a nice way to formulate it. I would use the mechanism I proposed to reduce the backtracking a bit like https://regex101.com/r/rScP7R/1

Comment: @Jan Do you think it is prone to catastrophic backtracking?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: I mean, in general, I'd avoid nested quantifiers but here's no chance of catastrophic backtesting.

Comment: @Thefourthbird given the `\n` preceding your negative lookahead in https://regex101.com/r/Vij8mH/1, (a) surely the `^` is redundant since it's guaranteed to match; and (b) given  that `.` can't match `\n`, it shouldn't be possible to backtrack as that group can *only* match at end of line. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nick: Nope, that's true.

Comment: @Nick That is exactly the intent of the pattern with the negative lookahead and the newline. I was just checking with Jan as he also  knows his regexes :-)

Answer (score 1):

I only use regular expression when absolutely needed. In general, I find regular expressions hard to understand. However, in this case, if the original poster insisted, I would embed comments inside the regular expression to explain the parts:

```py
import json
import re

all_logs = """[INFO]: Waiting for application shutdown.
[INFO]: Application shutdown complete.
[INFO]: Finished server process"""

pattern = re.compile(
    r"""
        ^
        \[(?P<level>INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR)\]:  # The level, e.g. [DEBUG]:
        \s+                                       # White spaces
        (?P<message>.*)                           # The message
        \s*$                                      # White spaces at the end
    """,
    re.VERBOSE,
)

parsed = [
    matched.groupdict()
    for line in all_logs.splitlines()
    if (matched := pattern.match(line)) is not None
]

print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "level": "INFO",
        "message": "Waiting for application shutdown."
    },
    {
        "level": "INFO",
        "message": "Application shutdown complete."
    },
    {
        "level": "INFO",
        "message": "Finished server process"
    }
]
```

Notes

- The use of `re.VERBOSE` allows me to embed comments inside the regular expression, explaining each part
- I used the notation `(?P<level>...)` to name this group as "level", likewise, I name the next group "message"
- The `groupdict()` function will return the matched as a dictionary using the names I created

Comment: Regular expressions are not hard to understand "per se" and are often the easiest way to get the job done.